# Rails' export csv function "undefined method `export' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making an export to csv file functionality in a Ruby on Rails repo and I'm almost done. However, when I press the "Export all" button, I get the `` undefined method `export' for nil:NilClass `` error. The log shows that `format.csv { send_data @foos.export, filename: "foos-#{Date.today}.csv" }` went wrong. What am I missing please?

This is model

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars 

  def export
    [id, name, foos.map(&:name).join(' ')]
  end
end
```

This is part of controller

```
  def index
    @foos = Foo.all
  end

  def export
    all = Foo.all
    attributes = %w{name}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |foo|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| foo.send(attr) }
      end

      respond_to do |format|
          format.csv { send_data @foos.export, filename: "foos-#{Date.today}.csv" }
      end
    end
  end

  def name
    "#{foo_id} #{name}"
  end
```

This is View

```
<a href="/export.csv"><button class="btn btn-success">export all</button></a>
```

This is Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :foos
  
  get :export, controller: :foos

  root "foos#index"
end
```

This is Rake (lib/tasks/export.rb)

```
namespace :export do
    task foo: :environment do
      file_name = 'exported_foo.csv'
      csv_data = Foo.to_csv
   
      File.write(file_name, csv_data)
    end
  end
```

Comment: You're calling the method `export` on the undeclared local variable `@foos`. The whole thing is quite a mess to be honest. Don't do CSV generation inline in your controller. Use a separate class (for example a service object). I don't see how your rake task in any way relevant to solving the problem as rake is used to automate command line tasks.

Comment: @max Which parts should I fix, in the least amount?

Comment: I replaced ```send_data @foos.export``` with ```send_data all.export``` but it didn't solve the same problem.

Comment: Sorry bro but nothing here is right. Even if you disregard the nil error it's an instance method - and you're attempting to call it on an entire collection of records. You also don't have to manually concatenate the attributes into a string - the CSV module does that for you. You just need to produce an array with the attributes in the same order as the headers.

Comment: I'm totally confused, this is my first time trying to do export to csv, what should I fix separately on MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a [service object](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) that takes a collection of records and returns CSV so that you can test the CSV generation in isolation:

```ruby
# app/services/foo_export_service.rb
# Just a Plain Old Ruby Object that converts a collection of foos into CSV
class FooExportService
  # The initializer gives us a good place to setup our service
  # @param [Enumerable] foo - an array or collection of records
  def initialize(foos) 
    @headers = %w{name} # the attributes you want to use
    @foos = foos
  end

  # performs the actual work
  # @return [String]
  def perform
     CSV.generate do |csv|
       @foos.each do |foo|
         csv << foo.serializable_hash.slice(@headers).values
       end
     end
  end

  # A convenient factory method which makes stubbing the 
  # service easier
  # @param [Enumerable] foos - an array or collection of records
  # @return [String]
  def self.perform(foos)
    new(foos).perform
  end
end
```

```ruby
# example usage
FooExportService.perform(Foo.all)
```

Not everything in a Rails application needs to be jammed into a model, view or controller. They already have enough responsiblities. This also lets you resuse the code for example in your rake task if you actually need it.

This simply iterates over the collection and uses Rails built in serialization features to turn the model instances into hashes that can be serialized as CSV. It also uses the fact that `Hash#slice` also reorders the hash keys.

In your controller you then just use the service object:

```ruby
class FoosController
  def export
    @foos = Foo.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv do 
        send_data FooExportService.perform(@foos), 
          filename: "foos-#{Date.today}.csv" 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You don't even really need a separate `export` action in the first place. Just use MimeResponds to add CSV as an availble response format to the index:

```ruby
class FoosController
  def index
    # GET /foos 
    # GET /foos.csv 
    @foos = Foo.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv do 
         send_data FooExportService.perform(@foos), 
            filename: "foos-#{Date.today}.csv" 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
<%= link_to("Export as CSV", foos_path(format: :csv)) %>
```

Comment: IMHO the whole idea of "exporting" records as CSV, PDF, JSON, XML that people get hung up on etc is kind of silly. This isn't Excel. In Rails style REST resources can be represented as a variety of formats and the request format is determined by the headers / extension.

Comment: its a blank file

Comment: This sounds like you're not testing it correctly. I can't see any actual tests so its hard to tell what you're actually doing. If you don't have any records and `@foos = Foo.all` returns an emply collection you're generating a CSV file with no headers and no rows - in other words an empty file. Write an actual unit test for `FooExportService.perform` where you call it with an array of `Foo` records and parse output string. Then write an integration test for the controller where you insert the records into the db and parse the response with the CSV module.

Comment: This is weird, I can see the data by running ```Foo.all``` in the rails console
, including name, bar_id, created_at

Comment: How do I write a unit test for ```FooExportService.perform```